# SQL - New ID for a partition

Tags: sql, oracle, row-number

I want to have an ID which is the same for all entries within a partition.

Thinking of a table with columns lie this (having a table with the three columns on the left

[image]

How can I generate the new ID on the right?
I thought about row_numer() over (Partion by)... but I could not find a good way to do it.

Comment: Why does the last row have the same ID as the first two rows? Is it part of the same partition? Why?

Comment: what is the rule that makes the new_id change?

Comment: I was going to say "name+attr" but the last row breaks that.. If there isn't a defined logic to what new_id must be, you'll have to nter it manually. If there IS a defined logic to what it must be, you don't need a new_id - you just use the defined logic, surely?

Comment: Why not partition by a column in the existing data? Date is usually a good one to use.

Comment: sorry I made a mistake with the new_id of the last row

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY name, attr) as new_id
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: I think it partitions on (name, attr) changing

Comment: @Hogan If you partiition, Every partition start with 1

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yes your are right - it worked for me with rank() over - Thank you